# How to resolve this, without providing any default value?

Tags: django

When I am trying to run python3 manage.py makemigrations it shows :
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'topic_id' to journey_template without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:

`enter code here`

```
from django.db import models

class Topic_Table(models.Model):
    topic_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    weightage = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    grade = models.IntegerField( null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

class Journey_template(models.Model):
    student_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        topic_id = models.ForeignKey('Topic_Table',on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    subtopic_id = models.IntegerField()
    journey_template_key = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: You have to provide some kind of default. Otherwise what will Django put in that column for the existing rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `topic_id` field on `Journey_template` model.

This model already has data on your database.

You have a few options:

1 - provide a default value (like entering the number 1)

2 - delete your database and start with a fresh migration

Answer (score 0):

If you table already has data, adding a non-nullable column without any default will violate the non-null constraint. Django migration doesn't check the table for data, so it assumes there is some.

If your table has no rows, you can go ahead and give it any legal default value. The default does not change your model, it just gives Django a value it can fill in. Since there are no rows of data in the table, it will have no effect other than to make Django happy.

If you table has rows, then if you can think of a sensible value to populate the existing rows with, then use it. Your other option is to change the model by adding null=True to the field and Django will just put nulls in that field for existing rows. (Later, you can put your own values in to those fields with Django or other methods and change the field back to null=False if you like. You will get the same question when you migrate but the answer will have no effect if the fields are not null). null=False is the default for any field in your model.